# GUI refresh 20-30 seconds after startup BeagleBone running Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am running Debian Jessie on the BeagleBone Black Rev C. On startup, I notice that the LXQt GUI appears and then after around 20 seconds disappears for about a second and then reappears. This is a problem because I am using the BeagleBone to display a kiosk app which autostarts upon power on. So the app autostarts but then after about 20 - 30 seconds, goes black for a second and then reappears. This is not good behaviour for the professional environment that the kiosk will be running in.

I am autostarting the app by placing a .desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart. I have alternatively placed the file in /home/debian/.config/autostart and had the same behaviour. Any ideas on how to correct this?

**EDIT** The .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sudo /usr/bin/python /home/debian/myFile.py
Name=myFile
Comment=Startup myFile on load
```

Comment: Maybe it's something in the graphics driver. Do you have any relevant kernel messages? You can get them with `dmesg`